# Different result between numpy.fft.rfft and scipy.signal.freqz

Tags: fft

I'm using the following two functions to calculate the frequency response of an impulse response: `numpy.fft.rfft` and `scipy.signal.freqz`, but I get different results. Let's simplify the problem using a small number of FFT.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as signal
h = np.array([1,2,3])
H1 = np.fft.rfft(h, n=4)
w, H2 = signal.freqz(h, 1, worN=len(H1), include_nyquist=True)
```

NFFT = 4, `rfft` calculates DFT at frequencies `0, pi/2, pi` which is exactly equal to `w` returned by `freqz`

```py
>>> print(w)
[0.         1.57079633 3.14159265]
```

However `H2` is different from `H1`

```py
>>> print(H1)
[ 6.+0.j -2.-2.j  2.+0.j]
>>> print(H2)
[ 6. +0.j          0.5-4.33012702j -1.5+0.8660254j ]
```

The DFT at $\pi/2$ should be $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(-1)^nx[n]$ and in my case is $2$, so `rfft` gives the correct result. The `freqz`'s [document](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.freqz.html) says it uses `rfft` if the following conditions are met:

1. An integer value is given for `worN`.
2. `worN` is fast to compute via FFT (i.e., `next_fast_len(worN)` equals `worN`).
3. The denominator coefficients are a single value (`a.shape[0] == 1`).
4. `worN` is at least as long as the numerator coefficients (`worN >= b.shape[0]`).
5. If `b.ndim > 1`, then `b.shape[-1] == 1`.

I think all of the conditions above are met. Why are these two functions give different results?

Comment: Something looks off. The values that you are getting are for [0,60,120] degrees which mimics what Matlab's `freqz` would do. You can try to set `include_nyquist = true`. That doesn't however explain how your frequency vector looks like

Comment: @Hilmar I did set `include_nyquist=True` in my code. So it seems a bug of `scipy`?

Comment: It's a bug of `scipy` and I opened an [issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/17289) on it.